# How to checkout code using Tortoise SVN for Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have added Tortoise SVN extension for VS code, but the problem is how to checkout the code, where as in eclipse we can provide the url and get the code, i didn't see same features in vscode.

Comment: what does this have to do with angular2?

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 Tortoise SVN extensions in the Marketplace (today), and none of them seems to support `checkout` command (at least based on its `README.md` page).

VS Code itself does not support SVN, so the issue is in fact, related to those extensions.

You should fill an issue in the extensions's repo, asking for the developer to add support for `checkout` command.

Comment: @user1671308 Do you have any news about this? Did the extension added checkout support? VSCode now supports a SCM API so soon someone will add an interface similar to what you have for Git today.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open your SVN folder in VS-code
2. You have to add SVN in to your VS-Code (go to market place and search for SVN), of 
   Publisher: Chris Johnston, which is also available on VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnstoncode.svn-scm
3. Then update or reinstall Tortoise SVN again (Just run .msi file again) (which will just reconfigure your SVN)
4. Then close VS-code and open it again with that SVN folder (You can go to direct that SVN folder, open CMD in that directory, than just right "code ." and hit enter)

Answer (score 0):

Also, a quick search makes it look as if Ankh could be added to VS Code. This plugin has been very helpful for my team, in seeing all of the options available in SVN. The SVN UI in my experience has a tricky habit of not presenting you with the options you were expecting at all times, when you are trying to perform operations from within an IDE.